# Array vs array [] for java

Tags: java

I am writing a program that will be heavily reliant on ... something ... that stores data like an array where I am able to access any point of the data at any given time as I can in an array.

I know that the java library has an Array class that I could use or I could use a raw array[].

I expect that using the Array type is a bit easier to code, but I expect that it is slightly less efficient as well.

My question is, which is better to use between these two, and is there a better way to accomplish the same result?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Do you know how many elements are stored in advance?

Comment: Do you really mean `Array`, or do you mean `ArrayList`?

Comment: Is [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) the `Array` you're referring to? This is just a utility class.

Comment: @Gabe +1 from the sound of it `ArrayList` is _probably_ what is meant.

Comment: I really did mean Array, but I was mistaken about the usage for it. ArrayList is what I should have meant.

Comment: @Foo Bah. I do not know how many elements, its a generic processor for Strings that will likely have around 50 elements but may have several hundred.

Comment: By looking at your first line, I understand you want data structure in java which allows to access any element by index.  You can use Object[] objArr if you know size of array during initialization. If not then use Arraylist or Vector. There is no "Array" class in java. There is utility class "Arrays".

Comment: ArrayList it is... thanks for the help everybody. I chose the answer that I did because it was the first to offer a compelling reason for the argument. Very useful info all around though so thanks

Comment: Possibly not quite an _exact duplicate of_, but *strongly* related to [When is an ArrayList preferable to an array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288237)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `Array` would be of no help -- it's not what you think it is.  The class `java.util.ArrayList`, on the other hand, is. In general, if you can program with collection classes like `ArrayList`, do so -- you'll more easily arrive at correct, flexible software that's easier to read, too. And that "if" applies almost all the time; raw arrays are something you use as a last resort or, more often, when a method you want to call requires one as an argument.

Comment: Ah. Thanks, ArrayList is what I am looking for and this answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

The `Array` class is used for Java *reflection* and is very, very, rarely used.

If you want to store data in an array, use plain old arrays, indicated with `[]`, or as Gabe's comment on the question suggests, `java.util.ArrayList`.  `ArrayList` is, as your comment suggests easier to code (when it comes to adding and removing elements!!) but yes, is slightly less efficient.  For variable-size collections, `ArrayList` is all but required.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, which is better to use between these two, and is there a better way to accomplish the same result?

It depends on what you are trying to achieve:

- If the number of elements in the array is known ahead of time, then an array type is a good fit.  If not, a `List` type is (at least) more convenient to use.
- The `List` interface offers a number of methods such as `contains`, `insert`, `remove` and so on that can save you coding ... if you need to do that sort of thing.
- If properly used, an array type will use less space.  The difference is particularly significant for arrays of primitive types where using a `List` means that the elements need to be represented using wrapper types (e.g. `byte` becomes `Byte`).

---

The `Array` class is not useful in this context, and neither is the `Arrays` class.  The choice is between `ArrayList` (or some other `List` implementation class) and primitive arrays.

Answer (score -2):

In terms of ease of use, the Array class is a lot easier to code.
The array[] is quite a problem in terms of the case that you need to know
the size of the list of objects beforehand.

Instead, you could use a HashMap. It is very efficient in search as well as sorting as 
the entire process is carried out in terms of key values.

You could declare a HashMap as:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

For the Object you can use your class, and for key use the value which needs to be unique.

Comment: Why is it down voted? Didn't the asker ask for an alternate way?

Comment: -1 "the Array class is a lot easier to code" - `Array` is a utility class, and it's been established the OP meant `ArrayList`. Also, `HashMap` provides features the OP doesn't need and is no longer ordered like an array or `List`.