# How to add , remove and retrive a value from array or arraylist?

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to add element in array dynamically.Size is not fixed.Shall I use arraylist or array?Datatype is same.I am adding the value from database whose type is int.Then which datatype shall I used?How to add and remove a value from array or arraylist?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412813/when-to-use-arraylist-over-array-in-c

Comment: use generic list i.e `List<Type>` ex: `List<string>`

Comment: You are asking three fundamentally different questions. 1) Should I use an array list or an array? 2) How do I add a value into an array list 3) How do I add values to an array?  See Jon Skeet's guidlines on how to ask a good question here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use Generic List instead of ArrayList to avoid overhead of type casting.

[See sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)