# A two-dimensional ArrayList returns System.String[]

Tags: c#

I have trouble with the value that arraylist returns.

I created a two-dimensional Arraylist that includes string arrays, when I try to get actual value of string arrays, I get `System.String[]` as output 
instead of actual value of the arrays.

Why do I get `System.String()` as outuput?

Here is my code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] employee_1 = { "Employee1" };
    string[] employee_2 = { "Employee2" };

    ArrayList main_array = new ArrayList();

    main_array.Add(employee_1);
    main_array.Add(employee_2);

    for (int i= 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(main_array[i]);                
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You should have a look at the [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.addrange?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem... Why are you using an `ArrayList` instead of a generic array or list, also this is not a multidimensional or a 2 dimensional array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063156/why-isnt-arraylist-marked-obsolete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when retrieving the items from an `ArrayList` what you are getting is a reference to an `object` instead of the actual type. Thus when printing it is calls the `ToString` of object (which prints the type's name) and not the string you want. In addition when printing a collection (like you are doing in your `WriteLine` command) you need to specify how to so do because it's default implementation is also as object's. You can use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2) to print all items in the nested array.

To correct this first cast to `string[]` ( `as string[]`) and then print, or better still is to work with the list object instead: `List<string[]>`. To read more see:

- [ArrayList vs List<> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2309694/6400526)
- [What is the difference between an Array, ArrayList and a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32020000/6400526)

So:

```
var mainCollection = new List<string[]> { new string[] { "Employee1" },
                                          new string[] { "Employee2" }};
for (int i = 0; i < mainCollection.Count; i++) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", mainCollection[i]));
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

---

As a side note do not loop to `2` but instead by the number of items in the collection. See: [What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/6400526)

Comment: And last, make sure that these `string[]` are not better of as custom classes with proper properties..

Comment: This time I get an error of "Anonymous Types" with "Employee1" and "Employee2". How can I correct it ?

Comment: @AhmetFurkan - you are correct. I have a mistake in the initializing of the list. See correction

Comment: Thank you @Gilad Green for your solution. I will be dealing with what you recommended to me.

Comment: @AhmetFurkan - You are welcome :) If at the end you do use this answer for your solution please consider marking this one as the one that solves the question for future readers use.

Comment: At last I could figure out  and can correct the code in your way. Thank you again. By the way I correct the marking of answer. Have  a good coding.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of `ToString()` function for an array.

To print the employees names, you need to iterate the array:

```
for (int i= 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
    foreach(string employee in main_array[i]) {
        Console.WriteLine(employee);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried that , I got an error about "GetEnumerator"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here, ArrayList always take input as an object. So, when you add string array at an ArrayList, it take an object instead of string array.

So, you should convert this object to string array and print it.
like below:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", main_array[i] as string[]));
        }
```

or may use below(both are same):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            foreach (string employee in main_array[i] as string[])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(employee);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have string[] type elements in outer ArrayList.
The best examples to enumerate are in answers above. If you realy need string content of string to be wtitten you should use

```
Console.WriteLine(((string[])main_array[i])[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

`main_array` is a two position ArrayList, each position contains a `string[]` this is, a `string` array.

If you use `main_array[0]`, this is a reference to `employee_1` which is a `string` array.

You should be able to reference the array strings by using `main_array[0][0]`

Try this:

```
foreach(var strArray in main_array)
{
    // strArray is a string array
    foreach(var stir in strArray)
    {
        // star is a string
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with second foreach loop. I get an error of "GetEnumerator". Can you take a look again ?

Comment: @AhmetFurkan that's because `strArray` doesn't know what type of data is inside `main_array`, so you have to explicit do `string[]` instead of `var` on the first `foreach`, also there is a typo on his 2nd `foreach`, should have been `str` instead of `stir`

Comment: Thank you @Prix, After I modified that you said, ıt worked for me.

Comment: @AhmetFurkan nice it works for you but you should still follow @GiladGreen 's advice and use `List<string[]>` instead of `ArrayList`, you can read more about why on the 2 links he posted on his answer.

Comment: @Prix All right, I will. I just wanted reason of this issue. I guess, figure out what is going on with that. Thank you again for your comments.

Comment: I guess I won’t try to help people anymore using mi phone. :), anyway i’m glad you took my idea as your new code base.