# Can I store different types in a C# array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to store multiple data type in an array of C# . I researched on this and found one answer. For example: to use object type, the code for which goes like this

```
object[] array = new object[2];
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do with it? What are you trying to achieve by storing different basic types in an array ?

Comment: @Apoorva Asthana what is the Inheritance tree of your objects? You can set up an array of something more specific then the object object.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the data types you plan on storing in the array.
To store different data types in the same array you must use their common ancestor - `object` being the ultimate base class in the .Net framework will enable you to store any data type inside this array.

However, if you are planing on storing types that derive from a more specific base class - you can use that base class.
For instance, if you have an `Animal` base class which derived classes are `Cat`, `Dog`, `Tiger`, `Snake` and you want to store all of them in an array, you can use an array of `Animal` to do that.

Please note that this also applies to interfaces. If you have multiple classes that all are implementing the same interface, you can use an array of that interface. For instance: `var myArray = new INotifyPropertyChanged[3];`
and inside that array you can put any class implementing that interface.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Array, you can use `ArrayList` to store values with multiple data type.

Something like:

```
   ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();  //It contains List of object but we can't perform LINQ operations
   a1.Add(1);
   a1.Add("Example");
   a1.Add(true);
```

More elegant approach would be use of `List<Object>`

```
   List<Object> a1 = new List<Object>();
   a1.Add(1);
   a1.Add("Example");
   a1.Add(true);
```

More about [Array, ArrayList and List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32020072/6299857)

POC : [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nnBKwe)

Comment: I agree with you but the scenario is not permitting me to use arraylist . I am bound to use array only

Comment: Instead of an `ArrayList`, I would probably recommend `List<object>`.

Comment: I agree we can use `List<Object>` as well

Comment: @Apoorva Asthana: You say you are bound array. I'm tempted to ask: why? When using a List<object> you can easily do myList.ToArray() at any time. However: If you are bound to array, then your example solution is correct.

Comment: @ApoorvaAsthana, Please elaborate your usecase